# Is there a way to use multi-character delimiters in Open Office Calc CSV file format?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Is there a way to save a CSV file with multi-character delimiters? When I enter more than one character, it just uses the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, CSV ("Comma-Separated-Values", or "Character-Separated-Values") files by nature use a *single character* as a separator.

Usually a Comma, but not exclusively.

More info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to find a way to unambiguously delimit a file with varying data.